# MYSQL select statement with a case

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query which require two tables. The query is meant to return the value of the column tReduit or tPlein (in the table tarif) depending of what's written in the column grilleTarif and idUser (table client).

First table : client

```
 nom   prenom     mail          adresse              idUser                            grilleTarif
 admin admin admin@admin.com 10 rue de l'admin m(à"éàé"àé'à_ç-&'à&&=&-&é&à&&&é(è&é_è(§ tPlein
```

Second table : tarif

```
tReduit tPlein nomActivity nPlace 
2        3      NULL       NULL 
7        8      aquaPoney  10
```

My query :

```
SELECT
    tarif.tReduit, 
    tarif.tPlein, 
    client.grilleTarif, 
    CASE grilleTarif 
        WHEN 'tReduit' 
            THEN tarif.tReduit 
        WHEN 'tPlein' 
            THEN tarif.tPlein
        ELSE tarif.tPlein
        END AS X
FROM tarif, client 
WHERE client.idUser = m(à"éàé"àé'à_ç-&'à&&=&-&é&à&&&é(è&é_èpp§, tarif.nomActivity IS NULL;
```

I have a syntax error when I execute it.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE grilleTarif WHEN 'tReduit' then tarif.tReduit when 'tPlein' then tarif.tPle' at line 1.  

Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 153)
Unexpected token.(near "tarif" at position 156)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position161) 
Unexpected token. (near "tPlein" at position 162)
```

The other query I'm trying to do from [How to join row values to column names in a dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813615/how-to-join-row-values-to-column-names-in-a-dynamic-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
SELECT grilleTarif FROM client c
    INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT tarifCol, tarif from tarif t
        unpivot 
        (
              tarif
              for tarifCol in ([tPlein], [tReduit]) 

        ) unpiv
    ) d
         on c.grilleTarif=t.tarifCol 
where c.idUser = m(à"éàé"àé'à_ç-&'à&&=&-&é&à&&&é(è&é_è(§
and t.nomActivity is NULL;
```

I still have the error #1064 error of syntax

```
[...]near 'unpivot (tarif for tarifCol in ([tPlein], [tReduit])) unpiv )
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 114)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 121)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 124)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 132)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the complete error message. It looks like there are quite a few syntax errors, but I would start by properly quoting values. Also, you should use the more modern JOIN syntax instead of the archaic FROM comma style. It's still supported for legacy reasons.

Comment: You forgot a `,` before `CASE`

Comment: @DEarTh yes that's right thank you !

Comment: @SloanThrasher Do I need to use JOIN ? I don't have really have related column. I edited my question, there's the complete error message. What am I supposed to write after [END AS] ? I'm not sure if have an understood .

Comment: If you have multiple tables, you have a join. They have to be related in some way, otherwise, just reference one table.

Comment: @DEarTh Thank you I appreciate but it's not really what I'm looking for. The link between those two table is the value inside the column `grilleTarif`. The value can be either `tReduit` or `tPlein`. It's the reason why I need the table tarif. I'm going to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813615/how-to-join-row-values-to-column-names-in-a-dynamic-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In your first query you also have a , in your WHERE clause (between idUser and nomActivity) that should be AND. Fixing that looks like it makes the query work (see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bd2f/3))

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much you solved my issue !

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

**Query functional:**

```
SELECT
    tarif.tReduit, 
    tarif.tPlein, 
    client.grilleTarif, 
    CASE client.grilleTarif 
        WHEN 'tReduit' 
            THEN tarif.tReduit 
        WHEN 'tPlein' 
            THEN tarif.tPlein
        ELSE tarif.tPlein
        END AS 'Tarif en vigueur'
FROM tarif 
JOIN client 
WHERE client.nom = 'admin' and tarif.nomActivity IS NULL;
```